# Sinch - Message Api not working

Tags: android, base64

Always getting the Bad Request error, error code - 400. Using commons-codec-1.10 jar file but its not available for native Android. here is my code

```
Date date = new java.util.Date();
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
  "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

String timestamp = dateFormat.format(date);
String httpVerb = "POST";
String path = "/v1/sms/" + "+918003059919";
String contentType = "application/json";
String canonicalizedHeaders = "x-timestamp:" + timestamp;
String body = "{\"message\":\"" + "Hiiii" + "\"}";

byte[] data = md5Digest(body);

String contentMd5 = Base64.encodeToString(data, 0, data.length,
  Base64.DEFAULT);

String stringToSign = httpVerb + "\n" + contentMd5 + "\n"
  + contentType + "\n" + canonicalizedHeaders + "\n"
  + path;

String signature = signature(SinchService.APP_SECRET,
  stringToSign);

String authorization = "Application " + SinchService.APP_KEY
  + ":" + signature;

URL url = new URL("https://messagingApi.sinch.com" + path);
HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url
  .openConnection();

connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
connection.setRequestProperty("content-type",
  "application/json");
connection.setRequestProperty("x-timestamp", timestamp);
connection.setRequestProperty("authorization", Base64.encodeToString(authorization.getBytes(),Base64.DEFAULT));

OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
os.write(body.getBytes());
StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
int status = connection.getResponseCode();

System.out.println("resonse code: "+status);
InputStream iresponse = connection.getInputStream();

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
  connection.getInputStream()));

String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
 response.append(line);
br.close();
os.close();
```

Using android.util.Base64 package to encode but not its not working.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean when you say the Base64 encoding isn't working?

Comment: I am sorry about confusion. Earlier I believed that the issue is related to base 64 encoding as I didn’t use codec lib as suggest on sinch.com website in android as it is not compatible. This codec lib is used to do base64 encoding.
Now I tested this on core java and confirmed that error is not due to base64. Also you  replied to this question that error was related to whitelisting and my account is now whitelisted but it still not working. The API still gives us http 400 bad request error.

Answer (score 1):

Sinch applications are not automatically whitelisted for sending SMS. Contact them at dev@sinch.com to get your app whitelisted.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: The error they're getting is because their app is not whitelisted for sending sms. I provided instructions for how to fix this.

Comment: Okay, thanks for clarification that this problem cannot be solved programmatically.